# How do I check a palindrome in Perl?

Tags: perl

I am trying to write a palindrome checker in Perl. It's supposed to return `"true"` if the input is the same forwards and backwards.

**Example:**

```
./determine kayak
True
./determine "Do geese see God?"
True
./determine "Do ducks see God?"
False
```

**My code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w 

$name = $ARGV[0];
$name = lc $name;
$name =~ s/[^a-z]//g;
@all = split //,$name;
$half = $#all/2;

foreach $i (0..$half){
    my $count = 0;
    if($all[$i] eq $all[-($i+1)]){
        #print"$all[$i]\n";
        #print"$all[-($i+1)]\n";
        print "true\n";
        last;       
    }else{
        print "flase\n";
    }

}
```

It can't determine true or false after read all.

For example:
when read: `"Do ducks see God?"`, the first two letter is same, so it will print true, but this should be false.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please make sure your code includes `use strict'` and `use warnings;`. These pragmas will help you spot mistakes. (You have the `-w` in the shebang, but `use warnings` is the more modern form). You can then [edit] your question to include the updated code and any warnings it may throw.

Comment: Also, see [reverse](http://p3rl.org/reverse).

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/11165/5202

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code only checks the first letter and then stops the loop if they are the same. You've correctly identified that problem. It's because of the [`last`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/last.html).

```
foreach $i (0..$half){
    my $count = 0;
    if($all[$i] eq $all[-($i+1)]){
        print "true\n";
        last;                       # <-- here
    }else{
        print "flase\n";
    }
}
```

This will make Perl exit the loop. What you want to do instead is keep checking every letter. Once you've reached the middle, your result is true because the string is a [palindrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindrome). But as soon as you see a mismatch, you have to fail and exit.

You do that by keeping a status in a variable, and checking afterwards. I've added `strict` and `warnings` and made the code a bit shorter.

```
my $name = lc 'Do ducks see God?';
$name =~ s/[^a-z]//g;
my @all = split //, $name;
my $half = $#all / 2;

my $is_palindrome = 1;
foreach my $i ( 0 .. $half ) {
    my $count = 0;
    if ( $all[$i] ne $all[ -( $i + 1 ) ] ) {
        $is_palindrome = 0;
        last;
    }
}

if ($is_palindrome) {
    print "true\n";
} else {
    print "false\n";
}
```

It's easier to use a [`ne` check](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ne.html), because having an empty block after the [`if`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/if.html) like this is confusing.

```
if ( 1 == 0 ) {
} else {
    # do stuff
}
```

It's easier to turn the condition around and get rid of the block, or use [`unless`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unless.html), which is the same as *if not* in Perl.

```
if ( 1 != 0 ) {
    # do stuff
}

unless ( 1 == 0 ) {
    # do stuff
}
```

---

Note that there is a way shorter implementation: You can compare the string with its `reverse`. The [`reverse` built-in](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/reverse.html), when called in scalar context, turns the string around.

```
my $name = lc '12321';
$name =~ s/[^a-z]//g;

if ($name eq reverse $name) {
    print "true\n";
} else {
    print "false\n";
}
```

Comment: Or, if you want to have fun **and** you want poor performances **and** you want to give headaches to people reading your code (don't tell me this never happens!!), you can use a recursive regex... `/^((.)(?1)\2|.?)$/` ;)

Comment: *The reverse built-in, when called on a scalar, turns the string around.* That's not strictly accurate, is it? :-) `perl -E'say reverse "foobar"'`

Comment: @DaveCross oops. :D

Answer (score 2):

Currently, you print "true" or "false" for every iteration of your array of characters. You really want to check each letter and only print the result at the end.

```
my $is_palindrome = 1;

foreach $i (0..$half){
    if ($all[$i] ne $all[-($i+1)]){
        $is_palindrome = 0;
        last;
    }
}

say $is_palindrome ? 'true' : 'false';
```

But, personally, I think it's easier just to check your `$name` variable is the same as its reverse.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $name = $ARGV[0];
$name = lc $name;
$name =~ s/[^a-z]//g;

say $name eq reverse($name) ? 'true' : 'false';
```

**Note:** Please use `use warnings` instead of `-w` and also `use strict`.

Comment: You stole my variable name... Give it back! :D

Comment: The `reverse` solutions needs to do twice as many checks, but I suspect that each check takes less than half the time as the checks in the other solution, so it's still faster.

Comment: The second solution works for me if `reverse name` is between parenthesis `(reverse $name)`

Comment: @saudic: Oops. Yes, I had a precedence error. I've fixed it by changing `reverse $name` to `reverse($name)`.